# UIPopoverController and UISplitView in iOS 5.1 -> unknown function: _presentPopoverBySlidingIn:

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, ipad

I can´t find nothing about:

```
    UIPopoverController _presentPopoverBySlidingIn:fromEdge:ofView:animated:stateOnly:notifyDelegate:
```

I got following error message:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController _presentPopoverBySlidingIn:fromEdge:ofView:animated:stateOnly:notifyDelegate:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

I start my iPad-App in Portrait-Mode. And because I need some steps to be done from the master-VC, I present the Popover-Controller programmatically via

```
    [ _masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

When I want to dismiss the Popover manually (via touch or swipe outside the popover), the above error occurs.
The problem exists since iOS 5.1.

Comment: It looks like this is a private method used by the 5.1 SDK to show the master view controller using the new "slide-in" presentation style. I don't know why it's crashing, but I'm having a similar problem after opening a UIDocumentInteractionController from a button in the detail view controller. Are you doing anything to change the master view controller between the time you show the detail view controller and try to dismiss it? Does the crash occur if you open the master view controller from the app interface rather than programmatically?

Comment: No, I do nothing between the time, and programmatically 

            [_masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];

did not show any reaction. I still stuck on that problem.

Comment: If you open the master view controller from the app interface (not programmatically), then close it from the app interface, do you see the crash?

Comment: @arlomedia, I have this issue and it does crash. An action in the MasterView opens a popover (segue, programatically), the popover shows behind the MasterView correctly, when I click on the popover (and the MasterView should close) it crashes.

Comment: I changed completly to new schema of apple with swipe gesture .. works perfectly